# script tag executed twice when called from an animated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

i have a countdown() function defined in a static js file, main.js:

```
function countdown() {
    var tID = window.setInterval( function() {
        var t = $("#countdown").html();
        $('#countdown').html(--t);  
        if (t <= 0) {
            window.clearInterval(tID);
            $("a.about").trigger("click");
        }
    }, 1000 );
}
```

I also have the following within the page content:

```
<div id="content">
  <p>Sorry, but no  page was found here. Redirecting you to the <a href="/">home</a> page in <span id="countdown">25</span></p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      countdown();
  </script>
</div>
```

`#content` is initially hidden and is displayed using jQuery (after being loaded with AJAX). for some reason this causes the `<script>` block to execute twice - once when the content is `display:none`, and once while the jQuery show function is being called. Thus my timer counts down by 2s at a time. (actually 1 at a time but 2 iterations happen almost concurrently.) if instead of animating the display of the div I simply execute `$('#container').css('display','block');`, the code correctly creates a single interval. Can anyone explain this?

I have an example demonstrated in jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rJHKQ/2)

Answer (score 1):

Copied your code into jsfiddle - this might help

http://jsfiddle.net/rJHKQ/4/

Because your html element has display set to none, when your change the display of it, it's redrawing to display - causing your method to be hit again.

Also edited your example and updated it: (moved your code out of the div)
http://jsfiddle.net/NpKvr/

Comment: this works but the key is that the countdown() function needs to be called from within the #content div. this <script> tag is embedded in a response from the server (ajax navigation).

Comment: "Because your html element has display set to none, when your change the display of it, it's redrawing to display - causing your method to be hit again". Then why when I change the display to `block` directly (no animation) it doesn't get executed twice? The browser is obviously still redrawing the display. I need a solution which still allows me to execute the code from within the div